# php function to schedule execution of a task at a certain time

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a web based app, written in `PHP` that work like a reminder app, so the user enters a line of text and a time to reminded, app gets these two and at the specified time reminds the user. I implemented the program completely, but for scheduling, I have a problem: the program should do other jobs in between setting reminder and reminding user, but the only function that I find that can do something similar is sleep(), but it seems that sleep() is not the best choice because in between setting the reminder and reminding the user, the program could not to do anything.

Is there a function in php that enables scheduling tasks and at the specified time, the PHP program runs the task.

I do not want `cron`, `crontab` , `scheduled task` or any other OS-dependent solution.

Comment: why don't you want to use crontab? you can write  a script which save data to database and do anything with that data at certain time.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812436/php-and-scheduled-tasks, it has some alternatives discussed.

Comment: "I don't want cron" sounds a bit like "I want to hammer a nail, but I don't want to use a hammer" - care to explain why?

Comment: @georg isn't there any buit-in capability in php that can manage some simple tasks in background?

Comment: Are you storing these tasks in a database?

Comment: So where are these tasks being stored?

Comment: If you can tell me how or where these tasks are being stored, I can help you further.

Comment: for now, that I want to implement a basic version of the app that work only, in the next iteration i will enhance it with some options similar to storing tasks in db.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69028/discussion-between-jason-bassett-and-xinhua).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to execute a task at specified time in PHP only.

You may create a condition comparing current time with the time the task should be executed and run it on every request, but that doesn't guarantee the execution at the exact time, since there may be no user requests at all.

This is what cron is for.

Comment: this is not a task that executes based on a normal event (I know time and time passing is event but ...). you ceate a task in reminder, then for example 5h later the app says "hey! you should do something!". if you want to check time to know when to execute the task and popupp the message, 1) it wastes valuable system resources (busy-waiting) 2) the program can not do anything else.

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible in PHP.

You may check if your host provide a cron-like option (mine provide an URL call scheduling).

Another option, if users are always connected to your web app, is to manage alerts in javascript and/or ajax.